# Setting a default structure for a Wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

**Background**

I am looking to have thousands of posts that are of the same structure. To do this, I want my Wordpress posts to have the right structure setup so that there little copying and pasting.

An example post being, each post having the following-

- Summary
- History
- Requirements
- Installation Instructions

  - Step 1. (img - float: left, content - float:right)
  - Step N ... Repeat structure of Step 1...
  - Step N+1 ... Repeat structure of Step 1...
- Notes

**My Questions**

1. How do you create a standard post structure within a Wordpress Post? Meaning - I want to have this structure setup when I click "New Post" so that I do not have to copy and paste each time.
2. Is there a way to setup a button so that I could click "Add a step" and it would then insert the appropriate HTML/CSS to input a new step in the section for steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for WordPress templates. Add a files to you theme directory, give it a name (template-default-structure.php). Inside the file you created you need to have the basic content like this:

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: Default Structure
*/
?>

<?php wp_head(); ?>

<?php

// All your code here

?>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

in the content area you'll add all the html and PHP for your page once and then apply the template from the page editor:

[image]

You'll need to add some fields to the page post type that you can use as source to the data you'll be displaying in the content area.

I'd suggest using a library like [CMB2](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2) if you don't know where to start.

To make life easier for you, I wrote the structure for you, you'll only need to create meta fields and identify them. Here is how the template would look like:

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: Default Structure
*/
?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>

<h2>Summary</h2>
<?php 
    $summary_content = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_id_of_summary_content', 1 ) );
    echo $summary_content;
?>
<h2>History</h2>
<?php 
    $history_content = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_id_of_history_content', 1 ) );
    echo $history_content;
?>
<h2>Requirements</h2>
<?php 
    $requirements_content = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_id_of_requirements_content', 1 ) );
    echo $requirements_content;
?>
<h2>Installation Instructions</h2>
<?php 
    $step1_img = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_id_of_step1_img', 1 ) );
    $step1_content = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_id_of_step1_content', 1 ) );
    $step2_img = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_id_of_step2_img', 1 ) );
    $step2_content = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_id_of_step2_content', 1 ) );
    $step3_img = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_id_of_step3_img', 1 ) );
    $step3_content = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_id_of_step3_content', 1 ) );
?>
<div class="step1">
<h3>Step 1</h3>
<div class="stepimg"><img src="<?php echo $step1_img; ?>"></div>
<div class="stepcontent"><?php echo $step1_content; ?></div>
</div>

<div class="step2">
<h3>Step 2</h3>
<div class="stepimg"><img src="<?php echo $step2_img; ?>"></div>
<div class="stepcontent"><?php echo $step2_content; ?></div>
</div>

<div class="step3">
<h3>Step 3</h3>
<div class="stepimg"><img src="<?php echo $step3_img; ?>"></div>
<div class="stepcontent"><?php echo $step3_content; ?></div>
</div>

<h2>Notes</h2>
<?php 
    $notes_content = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_id_of_notes_content', 1 ) );
    echo $notes_content;
?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Ah ok this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Emile I edited the code to provide an example that you can use. That's mostly everything you need to achieve the wanted result.

Comment: Wow thanks, I wasn't expecting that! This is exactly what I was looking for - setting custom fields, that I can define within the template. Just didn't know where to start. Thanks again, I greatly appreciate it